# React app on Apache Server

Tags: reactjs, apache, webpack

I am trying to deploy this react project https://github.com/tahnik/react-expressjs
and use apache server for static file. The example that I know that is working is on Angular, on angular we just run ng build --prod and this will create a dist folder where there is an index.html. On apache, we just serve the dist folder. But here we use React with webpack that not contain dist folder with an index.html so I don't know how to do that on your project.

PS : Sorry for my english, it's not my native language

Thanks

Comment: Use `npm run build` to generate the static files.

Comment: Yes but no index.html anywhere. Here is the package.json of the project 
https://github.com/tahnik/react-expressjs/blob/master/package.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `index.html` because it is a server side rendered application. In the repository you posted, the whole project is meant to be running as a server side application, there is no index.html file. Everything is served from express as you can see [here](https://github.com/tahnik/react-expressjs/blob/master/server/routes/ssr.js#L49).

When you run `npm run build:client` it just creates the js/css files. You would need to:

1. Create your own html and add css and js to it.
2. Add `html-webpack-plugin` to generate the html with all the css/js files already on it.

If you don't want to do that. You simply run `npm start` after your `npm run build` and the server will start. now you need to proxy from apache to this `addr:port`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'm gonna to test your solution